# Filter Specific Numbers and Sum Up

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given:

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2];
```

What I need:

```
scoreN = sum up all numbers with one
scoreST = sup all numbers with two
scoreO = sum up all numbers with three
scoreAA = sum up all numbers with four
totalScore = scoreN + scoreST + scoreO + scoreAA
```

Question:

What is the simplest (beginner friendly) JS code to filter the numbers and get the sum?

const array = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3,2, 4, 3, 2];

Something like?

```
const scoreN = array.filter(1);
const scoreST = array.filter(2);
const scoreO = array.filter(3);
const scoreAA = array.filter(4);

const totalScore = scoreN + scoreST + scoreO + scoreAA
```

Comment: Why even filter don't you add up all numbers anyway? (At the moment your adding up arrays this wont work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach was quite correct.

But the array method `filter` takes a function which you can express with a lambda function `x => x === 1` in which the argument `x` represents the current array value. The return value should be a boolean, in this case we want all numbers equal to 1.

The function `reduce` takes 2 arguments a function with the previous value and the current value and a default value if the array is empty. In this case 0 if there are no elements to sum up.

```js
const numbers = [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2];

const sum = (a, b) => a + b;

const scoreN = numbers.filter(x => x === 1).reduce(sum, 0);
const scoreST = numbers.filter(x => x === 2).reduce(sum, 0);
const scoreO = numbers.filter(x => x === 3).reduce(sum, 0);
const scoreAA = numbers.filter(x => x === 4).reduce(sum, 0);

const total = scoreN + scoreST + scoreO + scoreAA;

console.log(total);
```

Comment: But I need the sums of all the ones, twos, threes, and fours to be separate.

Comment: Ok then you can do it like this

Comment: This looks great. Can you please explain at bit more? Maybe by editing the code with comments?

What does this line mean: (a, b) => a + b;

Is this some type of value declaration? Search for "x" where "x" is equal to ? x => x === 1

Please comment on: reduce(sum, 0)

Comment: Did it, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Yep, using `filter` you can filter the arrays down. However if you use `reduce` then you can filter and sum at the same time. E.g.:

```js
const scoreN = numbers.reduce((sum, val) => {
    if (val === 1) {
        sum += val;
    }
    return sum;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what these steps mean? Tried running it and got an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'scoreN'. Expected ';' after variable declaration.

line 5, column 0

> const scoreOne = array.ficonst scoreN = array.reduce((sum, val) => {
>     if (val === 1) {
>         sum += val;

Comment: Ah yep, one mo'

Comment: Just reading back, @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze's edited answer explains it quite succinctly and correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The most beginner friendly code, that works the same for most c-like languages would be:

```
function score(array, value) {  
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let element = array[i];
        if (element === value) {
            sum += element;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

another solutions that makes use of JS array functions would be:

```
function score(array, value) {
    let sum = array
        .filter(e => e === value)
        .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
    return sum;
}
```

you would use both functions the same way:

```
const scoreN = score(array, 1);
const scoreST = score(array, 2);
const scoreO = score(array, 3);
const scoreAA = score(array, 4);

const totalScore = scoreN + scoreST + scoreO + scoreAA;
```